# What is the effect of differences in flow and return rates in a traditional gas central heating system?

Tags: central-heating, boiler

Would a smaller or lower differential in flow and return rates in a traditional gas boiler "Y" central heating system make the house take longer to heat up?  Is there any way to adjust these flow rates on a traditional gas fired boiler?

Comment: Is this a physics or thermodynamics homework assignment?

Comment: Neither - it's a problem I have with my heating.

Comment: is your system a gravity fed or a combination boiler as described here: http://www.gasapplianceguide.co.uk/central_heating_systems.htm

Comment: Its a gravity fed boiler system.

Comment: @user13906 because of your multiple accounts and comments being posted as answers, your question was automatically locked. Please see http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts after you register an account so you can properly comment on your question.